# getting dynamic symbol table information from elf

Tags: c, elf

I'm trying to get the dynamic & static symbol table information from elf.

That's the code I wrote:

```
void symbols(){
    int  i;
    Elf32_Ehdr *header; /* this will point to the header structure */
    header = (Elf32_Ehdr *) map_start;

    Elf32_Shdr *shdr = (Elf32_Shdr *)(map_start + header->e_shoff);

    int shnum = header->e_shnum;
    const char * str_p =NULL;
    Elf32_Shdr *sh_strtab = &shdr[header->e_shstrndx];

    const char *const sh_strtab_p = map_start + sh_strtab->sh_offset;
    int j;

    int k;

    for (i = 0; i < shnum; ++i) {
       if ((shdr[i].sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB)||(shdr[i].sh_type==SHT_DYNSYM)){
          str_p =(char *) shdr[shdr[i].sh_link].sh_offset;
          Elf32_Sym *symboler =(Elf32_Sym *)(map_start + shdr[i].sh_offset);
          for(j=0;j<(shdr[i].sh_size/shdr[i].sh_entsize);j++){
              printf("%u ", symboler->st_size); 
              printf("%x ", symboler->st_value); 
              printf("%u ", symboler->st_shndx);
              printf("%s\n",(char *) ((int)map_start+ (int)str_p + symboler->st_name));
              symboler++;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is with the dynamic symbol table, for example:

```
 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 __gmon_start__
 0 0 0 __libc_start_main
 0 0 0 fopen
 0 0 0 fgetc
 0 0 0 printf
 0 0 0 atoi
 4 80485dc 15 _IO_stdin_used
```

When I'm using *readelf* I'm getting this name:

```
 0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
 1: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
 2: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
 3: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fopen@GLIBC_2.1 (3)
 4: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fgetc@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
 5: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
 6: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND atoi@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
 7: 080485dc     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 _IO_stdin_used
```

Why do I get `atoi` in my version and `atoi@GLIBC_2.0 (2)` in *readelf*? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readelf` displays information about the symbol version besides its name.

Symbol versioning is explained [here](https://people.freebsd.org/~deischen/symver/freebsd_versioning.txt).

> ### Symbol versioning - simple explanation
>
> Symbol versioning allows a library to define its exported symbols
>   through the use of a map file.  It also allows one library to
>   provide multiple versions of the same symbol.  In the past,
>   without symbol versioning, this was accomplished by bumping
>   the shared library version (libfoo.so.1, libfoo.so.2, etc.).
>   Now one library version can provide multiple versions of the
>   same symbol.

For more details, see [this page](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/symversion.html).